# Already using sqflite database for mobile App which is not supporting to WebApp,can i use different library for web App in same if yes than which lib

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, sqflite, flutter-packages

i am using sqflite library for database but it is supporting to IOS/Android app can i use to database for App existing one(Sqflite) and for webApp different in the same app if I can then how and which will be the best.Thanks

Comment: `sembast_sqflite: ^2.0.0+1 `  package use for web

Comment: `sembast: ^3.1.2` https://pub.dev/packages/sembast

Comment: i am not able to use that library.actually i there is already db sqflite which is working fine for mobile app problem is in web app. i am not able to find proper solution for that

Comment: you can use this library for web .it support on all platform.the documentation .they said they using sqlite for mobile developemnt.web sembast not much stable but you can use for web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use a separate package for the web. Now, to check whether your app is running on web or not:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```

If your use-case is just to store small values, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) which is supported for both web and mobile.

You can also try [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) which is supported for both.

Comment: I am doing operations like download and save delete bookmark using sqflite database in my project it is working fine on ios/android, but now i want to create app for web too in which it is creating problem because sqflite doesn't support to web app for that i want suggestions about which library would be fine for that and how to use that.

Comment: You can use hive or shared_preference